# Why is Amavis giving a Retry limit exceeded / File exists error on startup?

Tags: amavis

I noticed my mail server was getting some `service temporarily unavailable` errors and wasn't able to deliver emails, so after digging into it I found the cause was Postfix was unable to connect to Amavis.

When I looked at Amavis' logging (which I found in `/var/log/mail.warn`), I found this:

```
[snip] (!!)TROUBLE in pre_loop_hook: db_init: BDB no dbS: BDB0002 __fop_file_setup:  Retry limit (100) exceeded, File exists. at (eval 91) line 318.
[snip] (!)_DIE: Suicide () TROUBLE in pre_loop_hook: db_init: BDB no dbS: BDB0002 __fop_file_setup:  Retry limit (100) exceeded, File exists. at (eval 91) line 318.
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

I'm running Debian, and I believe I had both updated packages and rebooted shortly before this started happening, so maybe an update broke something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm self-answering this question because I have found a solution, but I still don't know why this happened, so if anyone else has any insight on that I'd be happy to hear it.

---

I saw a reference to `/var/lib/amavis/db` when I tried manually running `amavis-new`, so I moved that folder to `db.bak` (and after Amavis complained about the folder not existing, created a new folder with the same `amavis:amavis 750` perms).  Amavis was able to start successfully after that, and my emails began to be delivered again.

As mentioned, I am still not sure why this happened, though it might be related to the package update mentioned in the question.

I also don't know if there's anything important in that Amavis database, thus I moved it aside rather than deleting it completely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue here, in fact it happened now the second time within a week. amavisd-new version is amavisd-new-2.10.1 (20141025).

My workaround was the following:

```
rm /var/lib/amavis/db/*
/etc/init.d/amavis restart
/etc/init.d/amavis-mc restart
/etc/init.d/amavisd-snmp-subagent restart
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

If somebody knows the reason why this occured, I'd be glad for someone to reply!